# multiply function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Multiply function does not work, answer not populating to the answer field,what its supposed to do is to multiply entries from A and B then populate it to field C but nothing is populated in field C...

Here is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td width="186">A:</td>
    <td width="90"><input type="text" name="A" id="A" size="8"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="B" id="B" size="8"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="C" id="C" size="8" /></td>
  </tr>
```

Here is the Javascript code that I'm using:

```
$(function() {
    $("#A, #B").keyup(function() {
        var a = parseFloat($("#A").val(), 10);
        var b = parseFloat($("#B").val(), 10);
        $("#C").val(a * b);
});
});
```

Comment: Is it PHP or Javascript? Or Java? You can name every programming language you have heard of, but it doesn't make the question much clearer.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine as-is (minus a `NaN` when only one input is entered): http://jsfiddle.net/wGksa/. My only suggestion would be to drop the second parameter to `parseFloat` -- it doesn't take a radix like `parseInt` does.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#A, #B").keyup(function() {
        var a = parseFloat($("#A").val());
        var b = parseFloat($("#B").val());
        if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
            $("#C").val('');
            return false;
        }
        $("#C").val(a * b);
    });
});
```